# What is the time delay between getting data and loading to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, uitableview, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm loading my UITableView from an Api call but although the data is retrieved fairly quickly, there is a significant time delay before it is loaded into the table. The code used is below

```
import UIKit

class TrackingInfoController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var table : UITableView?
@IBOutlet var indicator : UIActivityIndicatorView?
@IBOutlet var spinnerView : UIView?

var tableArrayList = Array<TableData>()

struct TableData
{
    var dateStr:String = ""
    var nameStr:String = ""
    var codeStr:String = ""
    var regionStr:String = ""

    init(){}
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    table!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    spinnerView?.hidden = false
    indicator?.bringSubviewToFront(spinnerView!)
    indicator!.startAnimating()
    downloadIncidents()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func BackToMain() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("SearchToMainSegue", sender: nil)
}

//#pragma mark - Table view data source

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1     //BreakPoint 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableArrayList.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.incidentDate.text = tableArrayList[indexPath.row].dateStr
    cell.incidentText.text = tableArrayList[indexPath.row].nameStr
    cell.incidentCode.text = tableArrayList[indexPath.row].codeStr
    cell.incidentLoctn.text = tableArrayList[indexPath.row].regionStr

    return cell     //BreakPoint 4
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    AppDelegate.myGlobalVars.gIncName = tableArrayList[indexPath.row].nameStr
    AppDelegate.myGlobalVars.gIncDMA = tableArrayList[indexPath.row].codeStr

    performSegueWithIdentifier("SearchResultsToDetailSegue", sender: nil)
}

func alertView(msg: String) {
    let dialog = UIAlertController(title: "Warning",
                                   message: msg,
                                   preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    dialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    presentViewController(dialog,
                          animated: false,
                          completion: nil)
}

func downloadIncidents()
{
    var event = AppDelegate.myGlobalVars.gIncName
    var DMA = AppDelegate.myGlobalVars.gIncDMA
    if event == "Enter Event Name" {
        event = ""
    }
    if DMA == "Enter DMA" {
        DMA = ""
    }
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://incident-tracker-api-uat.herokuapp.com/mobile/events?name=" + event)!,
                                      cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                      timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            self.alertView("Error - " + error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            do {
                var incidentList: TableData
                if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments) as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> {
                    for item in json {
                        if let dict = item as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                            incidentList = TableData()
                            if let nameStr = dict["name"] as? String {
                                incidentList.nameStr = nameStr
                            }
                            if let codeStr = dict["dma"] as? String {
                                incidentList.codeStr = codeStr
                            }
                            if let dateStr = dict["supplyOutageStart"] as? String {
                                let tmpStr = dateStr
                                let index = tmpStr.startIndex.advancedBy(10)
                                incidentList.dateStr = tmpStr.substringToIndex(index)
                            }
                            if let regionStr = dict["region"] as? String {
                                incidentList.regionStr = regionStr
                            }
                            self.tableArrayList.append(incidentList)
                        }
                    }
                    self.spinnerView?.hidden = true
                    self.indicator?.stopAnimating()
                    self.table?.reloadData()     //BreakPoint 3
                }
            }catch let err as NSError
            {
                self.alertView("Error - " + err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()      //BreakPoint 1
}
```

When the class is run, it hits BreakPoint 1 first and then hits BreakPoint 2 and then quickly goes to BreakPoint 3, it then goes to BreakPoint 2 once more. Then there is a delay of about 20 to 30 seconds before it hits Breakpoint 4 in cellForRowAtIndexPath() and the data is loaded into the UITableView. The view is displayed quickly afterwards.

The data is retrieved quite quickly from the Web Service so why is there a significant delay before the data is then loaded into the tableView? Is there a need to thread the Web Service method?

Comment: how much data is there? there should not be that long delay, can you just print timestamps in places where you have breakpoint comments and show us output?

Comment: `NSURLSession` handles putting the web service call on a background thread for you, so you don't need to worry about that. When you hit breakpoint 3 and reload the table, breakpoint 2 should be called, then breakpoint 4 a whole bunch of times. Is that not the order that is happening?

Comment: Yes, there are fifteen records and the data is not large. After I reload the table (BreakPoint 3) there is about a 20 second or more delay after it hits BreakPoint 2 again before it hits BreakPoint 4 which is strange, what is it doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting server response in a background thread so you need to call the `reloadData()` function on the UI thread. I am suspecting that the wait time can vary depending on whether you interact with the app, which effectively calls the UI thread, and that's when the table actually displays the new data.

In a nutshell, you need to wrap the `self.table?.reloadData() //BreakPoint 3` with

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // update some UI
}
```

The final result would be

### Pre Swift 3.0

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.table?.reloadData()
}
```

### Post Swift 3.0

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
}
```

Comment: The OP needs to wrap not just the call to reloadData but all the other UI calls as well. (Nice touch providing both the Swift 2 and Swift 3 syntax BTW. Voted, just for that.)

Comment: That was the problem, it now loads instantly, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The table view should begin to reload in a fraction of a second after you call `tableView.reloadData()`.

If you make UI calls from a background thread, however, the results are "undefined". In practice, a common effect I've seen is for the UI changes to take an absurdly long time to actually take effect. The second most likely side-effect is a crash, but other, strange side-effects are also possible.

The completion handler for `NSURLSession` calls is run on a background thread by default. You therefore need to wrap all your UI calls in a call to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` (which is now `DispatchQueue.main.async()` in Swift 3.)

(If you are doing compute-intensive work like JSON parsing in your closure it's best to do that from the background so you don't block the main thread. Then make just the UI calls from the main thread.)

In your case you'd want to wrap the 3 lines of code marked with "breakpoint 3" (all UI calls) as well as the other calls to `self.alertView()`

Note that if you're sure the code in your completion closure is quick you can simply wrap the whole body of the closure in a call to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you reload your tableview in inside the Dispatch main async, just immediately you get the data