# populating tableView with remote JSON data in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I want to populate a tableView with remote JSON data. Fetching is done in fetchRecentPosts method and it is called in viewDidLoad method. The problem is that dataTaskWithRequest is asynchronous and the table view doesn't wait for the data. I read in  [What is the time delay between getting data and loading to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744482/what-is-the-time-delay-between-getting-data-and-loading-to-uitableview) that I should write self.tableView.reloadData() in dispatch_async but it didn't work.

```
func fetchRecentPosts(){
    let url = XAPI.recentPostURL()
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        let result = self.processRecentPostsRequest(data: data, error: error)
        allPosts = result
        print("session task complete")
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

The problem is that allPosts is nil as dataTaskWithRequest has not finished its task.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchRecentPosts()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allPosts.count
}
```

Comment: Networking is an asynchronous operation. The right way to do this is to populate your table view after you receive data inside your `dataTaskWithRequest` callback.

Comment: Move the `dispatch_async` inside the task's completion block.

Comment: First specify the JSON object, its array object or dictionary then parse with NSObject modal class. Add these object on **allPosts** array after that you reload UItableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get away with a little hack.

In your `numberOfRowsInsection` method you can check the count of `allPosts.count` and if it is 0 (there's no data yet) then return 0, otherwise return the count.

Then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate you can adjust the view accordingly depending on whether there is anything in `allPosts` or not.

I recommend using `xib` files for your cells, you can perhaps have a `LoadingCell.xib` and a `PostCell.xib` and load them accordingly.

That way when your view is loaded before the data is set, it will display a nice message indicating that the data is being loaded.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. If you return `0` if `allPosts.count` is `0`, then all you need to do is `return allPosts.count` whether it is zero or not. And if it does return `0`, then `cellForRowAt` won't even be called so there is nothing to adjust.